Close a flyout from en embedded omniscript
The strcture of my components is the following:
A parent Flex Card
A child flex card that receives a list of data rows from the parent FC
For each rows, there is a button that when clicked calls an Omniscript
Parent FlexCard

Child FlexCard

The 'Accès' action is configured like this:

Omniscript

The Omniscript has no steps, It set the url initial value, then calls an IP to get the URL, then navigates to that URL.

The first problem is, by using an Action element , whenever I launch the ParentFlex card the omniscript is automatically called when the page loads, it doesn't wait until i press the Action.
Second problem: I changed the action element to a block with an embedded action, that solved the first problem, but the modal does not close after being navigated to the URL.

I did search in the internet, I set up a setValue element in the OS with pub/sub checkbox activated.
Then in the parent FlexCard setup, I added an event listener like this:

It seems like everything is correctly set up but the modal does not close.
I have tried the same config in a Trailhad playground and it seems to be working, the difference I see is that when creation the flyout in my sandbox I don't have the channel name selection as in the Playground ( as in the image)
Thanks for your help

I would suggest you discard the Omniscript - as from what I can gather, its only purpose is to run the Integration Procedure and then navigate to the relevant record page.
For you child Flexcard, you can use the datatable element to display the rows. The datatable element has some events that you can use, specifically rowclick. See some further documentation here:

Salesforce Help
Further examples

You can create the event listener to do exactly what your Omniscript is currently doing:


And then right at the end, it navigates to the relevant record page:

This setup gets you what you want and now you don't need to worry about the Omniscript modal not closing.
Good luck!

Hello, thank you for your answer
My purpose is to navigate to the link I get from the Integration procedure
Plus, I can't see any of the options you mnetioned in the picture when I create a listener
I'm using Vlocity 890 and I am not sure if it has all these options ( same as channel name I mentioned in the post that I can't find)
this is an image of the options
Event listener

@faouziCh I am using Omnstudio 250.7.1. You need to add the listener at the Setup tab of the child Flexcard (added picture to the answer). It should be possible to pass the URL from the response of the IP to the navigate action in the listener

@faouziCh I wanted to build you an example, but I couldn't get it to work. Ended up creating my own StackExchange question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/425997/flexcard-event-listener-data-action-response-node-not-working
Let's see what happens...
