Flexcard event listener data action response node not working
I am building a MVP where I have a Flexcard that displays 3 Account records in a datatable element.

You can click on a row and the rowclick event triggers.
I set up an event listener in the Flexcard's setup tab that runs an Integration Procedure that basically gets the Account record and returns the recordId:
{
    "accountRecordId": "001J50000052XQ3IAM"
}

Ultimately I want this result to go sit in the Flexcard's JSON as per the image taken from this Salesforce help article:

My setup of the Integration Procedure's Reponse Node field is exactly as per the documentation, but the IP's reponse does not get added to Flexcard's JSON.

When previewing the Flexcard, the Action Debugger also shows everything went perfectly.
The manifest file for my MVP can be found here.
Any help and/or guidance on how to get the IP's response into the Flexcard's JSON would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

I would suggest here to use a Set Values actions in a sequential manner after the IP action finishes execution and you can use the response from the IP in the Key-value pair you will set in Set Values.

how would the key value pair of the set values look like? I can put it in the Session e.g. Session:accountId but how would the merge field look like that gets the response from the IP?
